# Ask for reloding the data and image in tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I use the custom table cell and in this i put 3 or more **label** and and one **image view**  when I am use

```
[TableView reloadData];
```

at that time only data that in the **label** is change image is not change so plz give me advice for reloading image also

```
- (IBAction)reloadTableViewNext:(id)sender {
    i=i+1;
    AppDeleget.Page=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
    [self viewWillAppear:YES];
[TableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: You need to post your code for -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are changing the image according to the reload in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call

```
[self viewWillAppear:YES];
```

directly. If you like to redraw the whole view you can do the following in a view controller:

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

The

```
[TableView reloadData];
```

should be fine to reload.

Please post the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. It's place where you (should) set the image.

**Side Note**

Reconsider using caps at the beginning for variable/field names, like `TableView`. It's a common practice in OO langugaes to use capital letters for class names.

Comment: this code not give the result plz where to write [self.view setneedsdisplay] method

Comment: @user763657 in your viewController. However it was meant as a substitute for calling viewWillAppear directly. You've got to edit your question and post the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath, I don't think anyone can help without it.